# SimpleCursorAdapter crashing

Tags: android, android-layout

Android keep crashing as it hits the line "SimpleCursorAdapter NotesAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.manage_notes_noteitem_layout,)

I've tried changing all sorts of things, even creating a separate class for the Adapter, but the Adapter class also proves problematic. Either it's the "this"/context or something to do with the custom layout. I'm unsure and I have been looking around for answers.

Thanks in advance.

```
        String[] columns = new String[] {
        NotesAdapter.KEY_NoteTitle,
        NotesAdapter.KEY_Created,
        NotesAdapter.KEY_NoteText,
      };

      // the XML defined views which the data will be bound to
      int[] to = new int[] { 
        R.id.note_title,
        R.id.note_datedcreated,
        R.id.note_details,
      };

      // create the adapter using the cursor pointing to the desired data 
      //as well as the layout information
      SimpleCursorAdapter NotesAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
        this, R.layout.manage_notes_noteitem_layout, 
        C, 
        columns, 
        to,
        0);
```

Update for the NotesAdapter class:

```
public class NotesAdapter extends DBAdapter 
{

public static final String KEY_NoteID = "NoteID";
public static final String KEY_NoteTitle = "NoteTitle";
public static final String KEY_NoteText = "NoteText";
public static final String KEY_Created = "Created";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "notes";

public NotesAdapter(Context ctx) {
    super(ctx);
}

public long create(String NoteID, String NoteTitle, String NoteText, String Created) {
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(KEY_NoteID,NoteID);
    args.put(KEY_NoteTitle,NoteTitle);
    args.put(KEY_NoteText,NoteText);
    args.put(KEY_Created,Created);

    return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null,args);
}

public boolean delete(String RowID) {
    return mDb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_NoteID + "=" + RowID, null) > 0;
}

public Cursor fetchAll() {
    return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_NoteID, KEY_NoteTitle, KEY_NoteText, KEY_Created}, null, null, null, null, null);
}

public Cursor fetch(long rowId) throws SQLException {
    Cursor mCursor =
        mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_NoteID, KEY_NoteTitle, KEY_NoteText, KEY_Created}, KEY_NoteID + "=" + rowId, null,
                null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}
```

}

Edit: The cursor does return valid values because I tested it using Toasts.

Comment: Post the query to get cursor C

Comment: When you say it crashes, what happens?  Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4039086/debugging-simplecursoradapter.

Comment: What is the definition of KEY_NoteID? and post the logcat

Comment: thanks guys, the problem was the database connectivity in the end. I have another issue though. I have a separate class that Adds to the database, but I'm unsure if I should pass through the Database helper is a variable into the constructor of the class, or to access it as a static variable?

Comment: Alright, all sorted. Thanks all!